# Extent Picture by calculating size with a Photoshop-script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs4

I'm ALL new to Photoshop-scripting, and I can't seem to find very much documentation on this. I know some scripting, but as I've read Photoshop-scripting is mostly like JAVA-scripting?

Anyhow, I need a script that'll calculate the Picture and expand it if required. I know how I think it'll work, but I don't know how to write it. I need this for a other application I've made to edit `PNG` files. So it is always finished `PNG` files that this script will run on.

Here's how I would program it in JAVA (rather simplified):

```html
if (get.length/get.height>2) {
extentPicture.height(get.length/2, centered);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this piece of code?

Comment: In the condition of your if statement, is that the document length and height?

Comment: Hope this helps... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: @DominicFox yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly similar:

```
// Create a refrernce to the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get original width and height
var l = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

// Check the length/height
if (l/h >2)
{
  // resize the canvas
  app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(l, l/2, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
}
```